# Pgfplots: read table with global y error expression

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am plotting several curves with error bars. Principally, I do it with the code like this (for sure, the table is usually read from a file):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.13,
    error bars/y explicit,
    error bars/error bar style={solid},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            error bars/y dir=both,
        ]
        \addplot table [y error expr=sqrt(\thisrowno{2})] {
            0       0       0
            1       1       0.9
            2       4       0.9
            3       9       1.6
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: How the MWE looks like.]

However, I have a lot of plots where I don't want to repeat the `y error expr` every time. Thus, I try to move the local statement to the global `axis`.

```
[...]
    \begin{axis}[
            error bars/y dir=both,
            table/y error expr=sqrt(\thisrowno{2}),    % <-- added
        ]
        \addplot table {
[...]
```

Unfortunately, this yields the following errors:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/y error plus expr',
to which you passed 'sqrt(\thisrowno {2})', and I am going to ignore it.
Perhaps you misspelled it.
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/y error minus expr',
to which you passed 'sqrt(\thisrowno {2})', and I am going to ignore it.
Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

How can I make a single `y error expr` statement for all `table`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll consider this as a bug. Have a look at the comments in the code for a workaround.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        error bars/y explicit,
        error bars/error bar style={solid},
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        error bars/y dir=both,
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
%        % because the following line is causing an error ...
%        table/y error expr=sqrt(\thisrowno{2}),
        % ... we can use the following two lines to make it work
        table/y error plus expr=sqrt(\thisrowno{2}),
        table/y error minus expr=sqrt(\thisrowno{2}),
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot table {
            0       0       0
            1       1       0.1
            2       4       0.2
            3       9       1.6
        };
        \addplot table {
            0       1       0
            1       2       0.9
            2       5       0.9
            3      10       1.6
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]